# Why all pre tags don't have button element?

Tags: javascript, html, append

I write this code for website . i want to add a button element to all pre elements . but all pre tags don't have button on result .

This is my HTML codes :

```
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
```

and javascript codes :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
  btn.appendChild(t);
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
  alert(x.length);
  for (var i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
    x[i].appendChild(btn);
  }

}

myFunction();
```

```html
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're just moving the same button around. When you use `appendChild`, it doesn't **copy** the child you give it, it **moves** it. So your code is putting the button in the first `p`, then moving it out of that into the second `p`, etc.

Create a new button for each iteration of the loop.

From [the DOM spec for `appendChild`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-184E7107):

> Adds the node `newChild` to the end of the list of children of this node. **If the `newChild` is already in the tree, it is first removed.**

*(my emphasis)*

Live Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var btn, t;
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
  for (var i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
    btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    x[i].appendChild(btn);
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
<pre>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</pre>
```

Comment: Can you get an example ?

Comment: @SoftGroup: Huh? You know how to create a button, you're doing it in your code. I've gone ahead and modified the snippet from the question; see the updated answer.